# Image not resizing properly in navbar

Tags: html, css, image

I have a picture inserted in my navbar, through a div tag. The size of the image only changes, when the value is in a percent. Only the width changes the size, but it keeps the aspect ratio the same, so I'm not able to edit the width and height independently. How do I fix this? Oh also, can someone show me how to make it so that the navbar covers the top completely? thx

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 95%;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #999
}

.nav img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 17.9%;
  height: 0.05%
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2%
}

li a {
  font-size: 160%;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #81DAF5;
  text-decoration: none
}

li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: background 0.3s linear
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/28kL2hvu/1/

You don't want `div` in `ul` without wrapping it in `li` first. 
When using percentage on width and height, you need to set the parent container's width and height to a specific value. So that when you use a percentage value on the child div for height and width, they only grow to the specified value on the parent container.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="navpic.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">Page</a></div>
</div>

.parent {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #999
}

.nav img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2%
}

li a {
  font-size: 160%;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #81DAF5;
  text-decoration: none
}

li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: background 0.3s linear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you set to  `%ul a fixed height`, it must be an `auto height` or a height in `px-els` so that the child divs can use a % value to height.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    display: flex;
}
.nav img {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height:70px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2%
}
li a {
    font-size: 160%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #81DAF5;
    text-decoration: none
}
li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background 0.3s linear
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now. Your HTML is not correctly formatted. 
Inside %ul tag you must have only %li tags

```
<ul>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above peace of code can be refactored into

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why setting a fixed height to a %ul is a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem overall, there are cases if required to have a fixed height of the navigation wrapper and then to work around with inside content.

In your case you had and `float:left` to the image and the above parents can't know it's height. You can try to add an clearfix to the parents.

Comment: plus one for your explanation